# unity 3d's package manager is not showing ProGrids module

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-engine, game-development

### In unity's package manager the proGrids module is not visible

I installed proBuilder but the proGrid module is not showing up

[image: Here's the screenshot]

> **Unity version-- 2021.1.1f1**

If you want any more info please ask

THANKS!!

Comment: As far as I can see it says that it is experimental in 2020.3 .. maybe it doesn't support 2021 (yet)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Apparently even though it is (currently?) not appearing in the packages you can still install it via ([Source](https://forum.unity.com/threads/will-unity-2020-1-make-progrids-obsolete.752492/#post-7028305))

[image]

[image]

---

**Update**: in the newest versions the option `Add package by name` is removed and instead you enter the exact same thing into `Add package from git URL`

Comment: Unfortunately the `add package by name` didn't show for me, so i entered the name __com.unity.progrids__ instead in `add package from git URL` and it worked!

Comment: @Throvn yes in the newest versions this is now the way to go

Comment: Or you can add the package to Packages/manifest.json file

Comment: @LukášKmoch yes, that's basically exactly what these methods do for you ;)

Answer (score 4):

ProGrids is a preview package so you need to check `Enable Preview Packages` in the Package Manager Project Settings

Comment: Yes, but only in Unity 2020. It does not work with current Unity version 2021.2.5f1.

Answer (score 0):

ProGrids on unity 2021.1.22f1 is still experimental. I don't know if this is safe to use or not. [ProGrids Unity 2021.1.22f1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2F25I.png)